# Formula to convert from a rating system to another

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following scenario: a user has to complete a form with two or more chapters and each chapter having its share. The sum of chapter shares must not be greater than 100. For each chapter he has to write some comments and in the end select a rating. There are three ratings: "low performance", "as expected", "great performance".

Considering the chapters share and the selected ratings the user must receive in the end a suggestion for final rating. There are four final ratings "Poor", "Good", "Very good", "Excellent".

I have to come up with a formula to somehow convert those initial ratings and chapters shares in this final rating.

Since my math skills are very poor, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to assign weights (what you seem to call "shares") to the ratings for the various parts (chapters) of the form, to assign numerical values to the individual ratings, and then to compute what's called a [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) (or weighted average, or weighted mean), and multiplying the result by $100$.

For example, you could let "poor" have the value $0$, "good" $1$, "very good" $2$, and "excellent" $3$. Then you could assign weights of $1/3$, $1/4$, and $5/12$ to the first, second, and third parts of the form. Then if someone came up with

1. good
2. very good
3. poor

you would calculate the rating as $(\frac 13\cdot1+\frac14\cdot2+\frac5{12}\cdot0)\cdot100$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I got but user selects one of the three ratings ("low performance", "as expected", "great performance") for each chapter and in the end has to receive one of the four ratings.

Comment: @Psyche, I've done the best I could with my understanding of your question. I do not understand what you mean in the comment above. If you can edit your question to explain it more clearly, I will attempt to provide a better answer.